# Angular js ng-view rendered event

Tags: angularjs

How can I know when ng-view is completely rendered. Currently I have tried to use

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() { }
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() { }
angular.element(document).ready(function() { }
```

but all these are firing before view is rendered.

Comment: Did you try using the `onload` argument of the [ng-view directive](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, use the `onload` argument of the [ng-view directive](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Comment: I'm using `onload` and first time it works fine. but second time, when `onload` is triggered, content is not updated yet. Actually I'm trying to wrap loaded content into some structure, and first time it works but next times it doesn't!